# allong.es variadic function not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get the following error:

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /home/ubuntu/nodejs/test.js:4:10
    at factorial (/home/ubuntu/nodejs/test.js:17:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nodejs/test.js:26:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

When I run this code:

```
var variadic = require('allong.es').variadic;

var trampoline = function (fn) {
  return variadic( function (args) {
    var result = fn.apply(this, args);

    while (result instanceof Function) {
      result = result();
    }

    return result;

  });
};

function factorial (n) {
  var _factorial = trampoline( function myself (acc, n) {
    return n
    ? function () { return myself(acc * n, n - 1); }
    : acc
  });

  return _factorial(1, n);
}

factorial(10);
  //=> 362800
factorial(32768);
  //=> Infinity
```

I am new to nodejs. I installed nodejs and npm with apt-get and installed allong.es with `npm install allong.es`.

What should I do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `variadic` function isn't exported 'directly', but as part of `allong.es`:

```
var variadic = require('allong.es').allong.es.variadic;
```

Although this also seems to work:

```
var variadic = require('allong.es').es.variadic;
```